# Purpose of style 0x00000010

Tags: windows, winapi, statusbar

After spying Windows XP Regedit with Spy++, I found then status bar is used unknown style **0x00000010**.

I try make own status bar with or without this value, but I cant see difference.

I think, this style is missing [Common Control Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) value, because this value is missing in *commctrl.h*.

Can someone explain purpose of this value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, it looks that this constant is named `CCS_NOHILITE`. Curiously enough, it is not in the Win32 headers (`commctrl.h`), but it is (or was) in the MFC ones (`winres.h`).

Probably it existed in some early days of the Common Controls, it was undocumented, but it filtered out through the MFC headers...

You can find a bit of documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314236%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), but I don't think that applies any more, so nowadays it is probably a no-op.